# How to configure AWS Amplify's Storage.put to use a transfer accelerated s3 bucket domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I've enabled [S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html) using [Cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-accelerateconfiguration.html#cfn-s3-bucket-accelerateconfiguration-accelerationstatus).

The documentation says that after enabling it, developers need to point their clients to use the new accelerated domain name.

E.g. from `mybucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` to `bucketname.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com`.

However, AWS Amplify's Storage.put method is using the bucket name defined during [configuration](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#manual-setup) like so:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Storage: {
    AWSS3: {
      bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
      region: AWS_REGION
    }
  }
})
```

Since there is no domain name here, but only a bucket name, how does one set it to access the accelerated endpoint instead?

Comment: im trying to figure this out as well. Ill leave an update if I find something.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems to me that Amplify Storage doesn't support this configuration out of the box, so if you want to use Transfer Acceleration you will need to use the standard S3 client for javascript like so:

```
// obtain credentials from cognito to make uploads to s3...
let albumBucketName = "BUCKET_NAME";
let bucketRegion = "REGION";
let IdentityPoolId = "IDENTITY_POOL_ID";

AWS.config.update({
region: bucketRegion,
credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: IdentityPoolId
})
});

// configure the S3 client to use accelerate - note useAccelerateEndpoint flag
const options = {
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: bucketRegion, // same as your bucket
    endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('your-bucket-name.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com'),    
    useAccelerateEndpoint: true,  
};
const s3 = new AWS.S3(options);

// then use the client...
// ...
```

Reference for the class AWS.S3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

Comment: yeah, i was working on a dashboard and we used S3 client directly... when i migrated to AWS Amplify somethings didn't work out of the box, so i had tried to mix the 2 when we needed special usage...

Answer (score 0):

I also was struggling with this and stumbled on now to enable this with Storage.put:

1. Specify your normal bucket name, as you normally would
2. In the options object for Storage.put, set useAccelerateEndpoint: true (which I took from the above answer)

If you do a test, and look at the network console for the Chrome Developer Tools, you will see that Amplify specifies the correct path for the accelerated endpoint.

Comment: are you sure it works? It did not work for me.

Comment: Based on what I am saying in the Chrome dev tools, the path indicates using an accelerated endpoint, so yes, I am sure it works. And anecdotally, my users indicate a noticeable performance improvement.

Comment: Great, I need to do the same, Any other steps that you did to get this running? What I did was enable acceleration on the s3 bucket and added useAccelerateEndpoint: true in the options for Storage.put method, but after uploading the video the acceleration endpoint is still not used. What amplify version are you using?